# weird double-nullable variable error, why is it happening?

Tags: swift

sometimes compiler produces weird optional error with double nullable operator like `Value of optional type 'Data??' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Data?'`, I'm wondering why is it happening? is this a bug or quirk I dont understand? Here's sample of code to reproduce

```
import Foundation
public class testClass {
  var id: Int64?
  
  init(id: Int64?, completionHandler: (([Data?], Bool) -> Data?)?) {
    self.id = id
  }
}

let tC = testClass(id: 1) { datas, val in
  return datas.first
}
```

I'm not asking how to fix it, I'm just curious why this is happening as it looks like a bug for me - variable either exists or is nil

Comment: The element of the array is an optional, `Data?`, and `.first` returns an optional element so an optional of an optional becomes `Data??`, the compiler then complains since the closure is defined to return a `Data?`. I don't know if there is an official term for `??` but I have seen the the term double optional being used for this.

Comment: You didn't want a fix but here we go :), `datas.first ?? nil`

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating the issue with your example. All you need for demonstration is this, where `Wrapped` could be any type:

```swift
typealias Wrapped = Void
let optionals: [Wrapped?] = []
let wrapped: Wrapped? = optionals.first
```

What's actually going on in that last line, if you use the correct type, is this:

```swift
let doubleOptional: Wrapped?? = optionals.first
```

You need to provide a default value, for when the array is empty:

```swift
// `nil` is the same as Wrapped?.none, here.
let optional: Wrapped? = optionals.first ?? nil
```

And if it was safe to force-unwrap, then one `!` would not be enough, either. You'd need two:

```swift
let wrapped: Wrapped = optionals.first!!
```

You should probably question why you have an array of optionals to begin with.